# VB 6.0 code executed as soon as I move cursor on the statement while debugging.What can be reason for this?

Tags: debugging, vb6

I was debugging some vb6 code and faced a weird problem.Whenever(Just When the debugging control moves to the particular function) I move the cursor to a particular statement written in a function it(the function which i am calling through a class object) gets executed ignoring all the breakpoints.The code statement is written in a function and I am calling a function through a class object like ObjClass.Fun().

Is it Vb 6.0 debugging setting or something else?

Comment: Can you post sample code?

Comment: Is there a UserControl in the mix here?

Comment: If it's a property and you've got code in the Get method for the property then in trying to show the value of the property the debugger will execute your code.  As @DaveInCaz says, could you post your code?